# How to query out params in URL - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to extract the code from an incoming url in react native. I am able to receive the url and print it in my console but having trouble getting the param from url.

**My code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', callback);
  })

callback = async (url) => {
    if (url !== null) {
      const new_url = JSON.stringify(url)
      console.log(new_url)

      const urlCallback = new URL(new_url);
      const code = urlCallback.searchParams.get('code');

      console.log(code)
    }
  };
```

**I keep getting this error:**  TypeError: Invalid URL: {"url":"myapp://?code=ABCDEFG"}

I am trying to query out that code so i can send it as a param in a post request.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, it seems you're stringifying url object, not string. Try to parse from its 'url' prop instead.

```
callback = async (url) => {
  if (url !== null) {
    const new_url = url.url;
    console.log(new_url)

    const urlCallback = new URL(new_url);
    const code = urlCallback.searchParams.get('code');

    console.log(code)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

```
const parsed = queryString.parseUrl("myapp://?code=ABCDEFG");
console.log(parsed.query.code)
```